# Multi select options for Magento2 custom Attribute

Tags: magento2, category, multiselect

I have created one custom attribute for Category with Multi select option.I am trying to get dynamic values from source file but first value only printing in multi select please give solution and check my code what i did wrong.
`

```
    $school_model = $this->_modelCreateFactory->create();
    $data = $school_model->getCollection()->getData();
    $value1 = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          if(!empty($value['school_id']))
          {
            if ($this->_options === null) {
                $value1[$key]['school_id'] =  $value['school_id'];
                $value1[$key]['school_name'] = $value['school_name'];

                $this->_options =[  [
                                       'value' => $value1[$key]['school_id'],
                                       'label' => __($value1[$key]['school_name'])
                                    ]
                                 ];
            }
          }
        }

    return $this->_options;
}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

form an array like this. It will work

```
// Added brands

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $collection = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Mysize\Model\Brand');
    $option = $collection->getCollection();
    $optionsArray =[];
    foreach($option as $optionValues) { 
          $optionsArray [] = [
            'label' =>  $optionValues,
            'value' => $optionValues
      ];
        }
        return $optionsArray;


}
```